# Querying JSON key with values as JSON in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, json, openjson

I have these `JSON`:

```
Application 1:

{
"business_industry": "Agriculture",
"docs": [
    {
    "internal": false,
    "type": "Asset & Liability Statement"
    },
    {
    "internal": false,
    "name": "Privacy Consent",
    "type": "Privacy Consent"
    }
],
"quote": {
    "principal": 0,
    "short_id": "3856545"
}
}

Application 2:

{
"business_industry": "Construction",
"docs": [
    {
    "internal": false,
    "name": "Privacy Consent",
    "type": "Privacy Consent"
    }
],
"asset": {
    "model": null,
    "make": "3856545"
}
}

Application 3:

{
"business_industry": "Coal Mining",
"business_business_names": [
    {
    "business_organisation_name": "Centron Consulting Services",
    "business_effective_from": "2018-04-11"
    }
],
"lite_doc": {
    "total_sales": 0,
    "total_sales2": 0,
    "refunds_present": false,
    "payment_arrangement_evident": false
}
}
```

which are derived from `DataReceived` in my `Application` model.

I would like to **query all applications** and get the **keys with objects as values**. Because I will use those keys as **references for creating new models** in another database.

Something like:

```
+----------+-----------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|   docs   | quotes    | asset | business_business_names    | lite_doc                    |
+----------+-----------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| internal | principal | model | business_organisation_name | total_sales                 |
| type     | short_id  | make  | business_effective_from    | total_sales2                |
| name     |           |       |                            | refunds_present             |
|          |           |       |                            | payment_arrangement_evident |
+----------+-----------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I will then create five models: `docs`, `quotes`, `asset`, `business_business_names`, and `lite_doc` which have properties listed above. The objects can either be another `dictionary` or an `array`.

This code is currently what I have:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY
SELECT
    asset.[key] AS asset
FROM dbo.Application
-- SELECT ALL KEYS THAT HAVE OBJECTS AS VALUES AND DISPLAY THOSE OBJECTS' KEYS
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(DataReceived, '$.asset') AS asset;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
-- Do nothing 
END CATCH

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

But it can only query the `asset` and it's not able to do `DISTINCT`.

[image]

For some reason `DISTINCT` does not work in the query.

[image]

Comment: In future please do not post images of code or data, please only paste text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query

```
WITH docs AS (
    SELECT docs = STRING_AGG(j.[key], '
')
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT j.[key]
        FROM Application a1
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a1.DataReceived, '$.docs') j0
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j0.value) j
    ) j
),
quotes AS (
    SELECT quotes = STRING_AGG(j.[key], '
')
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT j.[key]
        FROM Application a1
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a1.DataReceived, '$.quote') j
    ) j
),
asset AS (
    SELECT asset = STRING_AGG(j.[key], '
')
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT j.[key]
        FROM Application a1
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a1.DataReceived, '$.asset') j
    ) j
),
business_business_names AS (
    SELECT business_business_names = STRING_AGG(j.[key], '
')
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT j.[key]
        FROM Application a1
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a1.DataReceived, '$.business_business_names') j0
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j0.value) j
    ) j
),
lite_doc AS (
    SELECT lite_doc = STRING_AGG(j.[key], '
')
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT j.[key]
        FROM Application a1
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a1.DataReceived, '$.lite_doc') j
    ) j
)
SELECT *
FROM docs
CROSS JOIN quotes
CROSS JOIN asset
CROSS JOIN business_business_names
CROSS JOIN lite_doc;
```

Each CTE selects the distinct key names. Values which are arrays need to be broken out a second time using `OPENJSON`.

And `STRING_AGG` does not support `DISTINCT` so you need a subquery for that. Otherwise you could have done `STRING_AGG(DISTINCT j.[key]`.

Finally you just cross-join everything to get it as one table.

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/IqYACnH0)

Comment: This worked, but is there a way to detect keys whose values are objects or arrays automatically?

Comment: You could use a more generic approach such as this https://dbfiddle.uk/LC_iTeE5 I suggest you make a new question for this, as the question as presented is answered.

Comment: this is perfect. I will post tomorrow once I get to work. Thank you!

Comment: Could you also post the answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76411130/12415287

Comment: No you're not supposed to cross-post. You should get a mod to merge one or the other in.

Comment: Noted. New question is posted here https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/328268/275121