# Detect keys whose values are objects or arrays automatically in SQL JSON Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, json, openjson

I have these JSON:

```
Application 1:

{
"business_industry": "Agriculture",
"docs": [
    {
    "internal": false,
    "type": "Asset & Liability Statement"
    },
    {
    "internal": false,
    "name": "Privacy Consent",
    "type": "Privacy Consent"
    }
],
"quote": {
    "principal": 0,
    "short_id": "3856545"
}
}

Application 2:

{
"business_industry": "Construction",
"docs": [
    {
    "internal": false,
    "name": "Privacy Consent",
    "type": "Privacy Consent"
    }
],
"asset": {
    "model": null,
    "make": "3856545"
}
}

Application 3:

{
"business_industry": "Coal Mining",
"business_business_names": [
    {
    "business_organisation_name": "Centron Consulting Services",
    "business_effective_from": "2018-04-11"
    }
],
"lite_doc": {
    "total_sales": 0,
    "total_sales2": 0,
    "refunds_present": false,
    "payment_arrangement_evident": false
}
}
```

I would like to **query all applications** and get the **keys with objects as values, automatically**. Because I will use those keys as **references for creating new models** in another database.

Something like:

```
+----------+-----------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|   docs   | quotes    | asset | business_business_names    | lite_doc                    |
+----------+-----------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| internal | principal | model | business_organisation_name | total_sales                 |
| type     | short_id  | make  | business_effective_from    | total_sales2                |
| name     |           |       |                            | refunds_present             |
|          |           |       |                            | payment_arrangement_evident |
+----------+-----------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I will then create five models: `docs`, `quotes`, `asset`, `business_business_names`, and `lite_doc` which have properties listed above. The objects can either be another `dictionary` or an `array`.

This code is currently what I have:

```
WITH docs AS (
    SELECT docs = STRING_AGG(j.[key], '
')
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT j.[key]
        FROM Application a1
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a1.DataReceived, '$.docs') j0
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j0.value) j
    ) j
),
quotes AS (
    SELECT quotes = STRING_AGG(j.[key], '
')
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT j.[key]
        FROM Application a1
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a1.DataReceived, '$.quote') j
    ) j
),
asset AS (
    SELECT asset = STRING_AGG(j.[key], '
')
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT j.[key]
        FROM Application a1
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a1.DataReceived, '$.asset') j
    ) j
),
business_business_names AS (
    SELECT business_business_names = STRING_AGG(j.[key], '
')
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT j.[key]
        FROM Application a1
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a1.DataReceived, '$.business_business_names') j0
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j0.value) j
    ) j
),
lite_doc AS (
    SELECT lite_doc = STRING_AGG(j.[key], '
')
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT j.[key]
        FROM Application a1
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a1.DataReceived, '$.lite_doc') j
    ) j
)
SELECT *
FROM docs
CROSS JOIN quotes
CROSS JOIN asset
CROSS JOIN business_business_names
CROSS JOIN lite_doc;
```

but if I add a new `key-value` pair where the value is either an `object` or `array`, I'd have to add another query as well.

How do I do it **automatically** and catching `DataReceived` values that are **not objects**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic column names are problematic. But if you are happy to get the data in the column format `ParentKey, SubKeys` as multiple rows then it's fairly easy.

```sql
SELECT
  BaseKey,
  STRING_AGG(SubKey, '
') AS SubKeys
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      BaseKey = baseKey.[key],
      SubKey = ISNULL(subKey.[key], arrayOrObj.[key])
    FROM Application a
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(a.DataReceived) baseKey
    -- type 4 is array, type 5 is object
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CASE WHEN baseKey.type in (4, 5) THEN baseKey.value END) arrayOrObj
    OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(CASE WHEN baseKey.type = 4 THEN arrayOrObj.value END) subKey
    WHERE baseKey.type IN (4, 5)
) j
GROUP BY
  j.BaseKey
ORDER BY
  BaseKey;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/WMPI6HeE)

- We begin by breaking out the root object into key-value pairs.
- We filter to only include arrays or objects in the value.
- We break out those into key-value pairs also.
- Arrays come back as index-object pairs, so we need to conditionally break that out too.
- We `DISTINCT` over the base key and sub-key names.
- Then simply group by base key, and string aggregate the sub-keys.
- We could have simplified to only one level of aggregation using `STRING_AGG(DISTINCT`, but SQL Server does not support that yet.

Comment: Thanks again! I guess I don't need the outer select with the string_agg. ssms doesn't format the new line properly and it's easier for me to just use the inner query you have